Rate of convergence in probability
I am reading the paper
In this paper, they proved theorem 7 which stated in the following way

Theorem 7: Let $p, q, X, Y$ be defined as in Problem 1, and assume $0 \leq k(x, y) \leq K$. Then:
$$
\Pr_{X, Y} \left\{ 
\big| \text{MMD}_b[\mathcal{F}, X, Y] - \text{MMD}[\mathcal{F}, p, q] \big| > 2 \left( \left( \frac{K}{m} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \left( \frac{K}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) + \varepsilon
\right\}
\leq 
2 \exp\left(-\frac{\varepsilon^2 mn}{2K(m+n)}\right),
$$
where $Pr_{X, Y}$ denotes the probability over the $m$ - sample $X$ and $n$ -sample $Y$.

Before this theorem, the author stated that the empirical MMD converges in probability at a rate of $O((m+n)^{-\frac{1}{2}})$ to its population value. I do not understand how they concluded this rate of convergence. Could you please remind me of the definition of convergence in probability with a rate and explain how it connects to Theorem 7?

The theorem says that there is a low probability (the RHS of the inequality) that the empirical MMD is much more than $(2\sqrt{K}(m^{-1/2}+n^{-1/2})$ away from its true value (the LHS of the inequality).
We say that $a_n$ converges to $a$ in probability at rate $r_n$ if $P(|a_n-a|>r_n)\to 0$, so $|a_n-a|=O_p(r_n)$
So the convergence is of rate $(2\sqrt{K}(m^{-1/2}+n^{-1/2})$. $K$ and $2$ are constant, so we suppress it, giving $O_p(m^{-1/2}+n^{-1/2})$

Hello, so it should be $m^{-1/2} + n^{-1/2}$ right ?

Because as you can see that, before theorem 7, they wrote that the rate is $O((m+n)^{-\frac{1}{2}})$

Those are the same.

+1. Pipnap, one way to establish that equality of asymptotic rates is to use the fact that $m+n+2\sqrt{mn}$ cannot exceed $4\max(m,n),$ which in turn cannot exceed $4(m+n).$ Taking reciprocal roots shows $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+n}}\le \frac{2}{\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}}.$$ A comparable inequality (bounding $1/(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})$) is even easier to demonstrate.  That's all you need to show $O((m+n)^{-1/2})=O(m^{-1/2}+n^{-1/2}).$

Aha, many thanks
